# Property Sheet (.prop) : how to refactor its filename and not break VS project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

If I rename a property sheet, **the text** of the property sheet will be changed.
However, **the filename** of property sheet will not be changed.
How to make **the filename** change along with **the text** automatically?

### Example

First, I create `foo` worksheet.
It will be saved as `foo.props`.

After that, I think `foo` is not a suitable name, so I rename `foo` to `bar` in **the project manager** :-
(left to right)

[image]

However, `foo.props`-file will still be there, **not** renamed into `bar.props` automatically :-

[image]

Thus, when I want to add `bar` to any configuration, my eyes have to search for `foo.props` in system folder.  (Actually, I should search for `bar.props`.)

This is error-prone.
The inconsistency makes me nervous.

### My workaround

Whenever I rename it, I have to delete the old `foo.props` in **Window Explorer** manually, then save the `bar` worksheet as a new `bar.props` manually.

However, others work-sheet reference in my projects will be broken.

I will have to add `bar.props` to all related configuration of all related project again, otherwise the project will be invalid (unloadable) : can't find `foo.props`.

### Question

Are there any better workflow?  What is it?

Comment: I'm used to just performing a massive search-and-replace-in-files with Notepad++. Be sure to completely close VS beforehand or it might get its knickers in a twist.

Comment: @Quentin Thank.  I didn't know that it can replace many files at once!   .... It is also good to know that "replace all" can be a recommended way in practice.   :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it "recommended", but I've given up on making VS behave sensibly so... good enough :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename it in file explorer.
Edit it in Notepad++.
Edit the vcxproj files that use it in Notepad++

I've never had a property sheet as part of my solution in solution explorer.
I've also never had a solution that was more than 45 projects where find and replace didn't work well in notepad++.

Comment: You never use property sheet, so what do you use in place of it? (to set include/linker directory/name of .lib) .... Do you use plain old project property?

Comment: @javalover I use property sheets all the time. what i am saying here is that they are not supposed to be added to the solution in solution explorer. They are to be referenced directly from the project file. When I say project file, I mean, the text inside of the .vcxproj file.

Comment: 2 years later, I have extensively used Notepad++ to workaround many VS-crappy thing.  This solution works in every case I encountered too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best workflow is to set the right name from the very beginning.

Comment: similar restriction as "never rename variable"  :(

Comment: I know it does not solve your issue but I don't think you should spend more time on this. You will pay more attention to this next time. It is not a big deal (unless you have undreads of files to manage, do you ?).